# Draw Google Chart after clicking submit button in a form

Tags: forms, google-visualization, form-submit, onsubmit

I'm having problem loading a google chart after clicking the submit button in a form. I came across many similar questions posted online but none solve my question, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815456/drawing-a-chart-after-a-click-of-a-button-in-google-visualizaton).
The structure of my code: I wrap the google chart code inside a `submitHandler: function(form)` , then wrap the whole submitHandler with a `$("#timeuseform").validate({})`, then the most outside is a `$(document).ready(function(){})` .

When I remove the google chart code, everything worked fine. When I copy and paste the google chart code into `submitHandler: function(form)` , the whole page broke down.

here the HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Time Use Survey 2014</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Do you sleep, work and play more than fellow Americans?</h1>
<br>
<hr width="100%" size="3" noshade="noshade" color="#8A8A8A"/>
<br>
<form name="myForm" id="timeuseform" method="get" action="#">

1. On average, how much you sleep per day?<br>
<input type="text" name="sleep" value="" id="inputsleep"/><br><br>
<div id="sleepbox"></div><br><br>

2. On average, how much time you work on your workday (excludes travel related to work)?<br>
<input type="text" name="work" value="" id="inputwork"/><br> and you are working 
<SELECT NAME="workstatus" SIZE="1" id="inputworkstatus">
<OPTION>full-time
<OPTION>part-time
</SELECT><br><br>
<div id="workbox"></div><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button"/>
<INPUT TYPE="reset">
</form>

<br><br>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//form validation using jquery validation plugin
     $("#timeuseform").validate({
        rules: {
                    sleep: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    work: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    },
                },

//messages to be displayed if input cannot be validated
        messages: {
                    sleep: {
                        required: "Please answer this question",
                        number: "Your answer must be a number with maximum 1 decimal point"
                    },
                    work: {
                        required: "Please answer this question",
                        number: "Your answer must be a number with maximum 1 decimal point"
                    },
                },
//display error messages style if input cannot be validated
        errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
        label.insertAfter(element);
    },
    wrapper: 'span',            

submitHandler: function(form) {

//setting the input variables
        var inputsleep = $('#inputsleep').val(),
            inputwork = $('#inputwork').val();

//code for question 1 on sleep

        if(inputsleep>8){
            $("#sleepbox").text("You sleep too much!");
            $("#sleepbox").addClass("more");
        }
        else{
            $("#sleepbox").text("You sleep too little!");
            $("#sleepbox").addClass("less");
        }

//code for question 2 on work
            if(inputwork>6){
                $("#workbox").text("You work too much!");
                $("#workbox").addClass("more");
            }
            else{
                $("#workbox").text("You work too little!");
                $("#workbox").addClass("less");
            }

//code for google bar chart starts here
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data1, options);
        }

    }   

});

});
```

I have uploaded both working (without google chart code) and broken (with google chart code) in my github.

Working without google chart: http://kuangkeng.github.io/keng-data-journalism/timeuseform/nochart.html

Broken with google chart: http://kuangkeng.github.io/keng-data-journalism/timeuseform/chart.html

Appreciate if anyone can guide me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `google.load` and `google.setOnLoadCallback` calls outside your jQuery code.  Use the callback to initialize your validator instead of using document ready:

```
function init () {
    $("#timeuseform").validate({
        // validator stuff
    });
}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: init});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @asgallant but this does not solve my problem (or I did the wrong way). I want the google chart to receive some values from the submitted form and draw the chart. So the sequence should be 1. load the form, 2. validate the form, 3. submit the form, 4. pass the values from the form to the google chart, 5. draw the google chart. Your code draws the chart before the form is submitted.

Comment: If you are using regular form submission, then the page will load the form's target URL, meaning that you would have to set up the chart to draw on page load in the new page, not in anything related to the validation or submission.  Depending on the nature of the form and the results you expect back, you could switch to an AJAX query, which would allow you to handle the form submission without loading a new page.